# Multiple lists in ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have multiple vertical lists with the dynamic data and UI that needs to be viewed in scrollview. If I don't give any height to the lists, the lists disappear. But I cannot give a fixed height to the lists. I need the height to be adjusted dynamically like UITableView.automatic dimension in swift.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a height constraint on lists
2. When u reload tableView put constraint.constant = tableView.contentsize.height

Please check and let me know if it works.

Comment: I have to do it in SwiftUI. Can you give an example in swiftUI?